# How to getItemID from sqlite with BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, baseadapter

I have sqlite column is defined like this:

```
public final static String S_ID = "_ID"; 
public final static String S_PHOTOPATH = "Photopath";
public final static String S_NAME = "Name"; 
public final static String S_POS = "Pos";
public final static String S_SCORE = "Score"; 
public final static String S_FIXED = "Fixed";
```

I'd like to getItemID from a sqlite helper class with a adapter class extends BaseAdapter. Here is my code:

```
public class Page1ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater adapterInflater;
    public Cursor mCursor;
    TagView tag;

    public Page1ListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super();
        mCursor = cursor;

        adapterInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCursor.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            tag = new TagView();
            convertView = adapterInflater.inflate(R.layout.page1listview_item, null);
            tag.imgV = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ItemImage); 
            tag.titleV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ItemTitle); 
            tag.descriptionV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ItemText);
            convertView.setTag(tag);
        } else {
            tag = (TagView) convertView.getTag();
        }
        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.S_PHOTOPATH)));
        BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getActivity().getResources(), bmp);
        tag.imgV.setBackground(bmpDrawable);
        tag.titleV.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.S_NAME)));         
        tag.descriptionV.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.S_POS)));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;            
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        Log.i("mCursor.getCount() --->", String.valueOf(mCursor.getCount()));
        mCursor.move(position);     
        long id = mCursor.getLong(0); // <--- error here
        return id; 
    }

    public void setTag (Drawable dwb, String title, String description) {
        tag.imgV.setBackground(dwb);
        tag.titleV.setText(title);
        tag.descriptionV.setText(description);
    }
}
```

However, the getItemID() always get error or wrong ID.

How could I get the _ID column value with cursor?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why dont you use SimpleCursorAdapter ?

Comment: I need getview() of BaseAdapter to custom the listview. Not familiar with SimpleCursorAdapter, can it do the same thing?

Comment: sure, in most cases you dont even have to override any method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Cursor.move()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#move%28int%29) moves the cursor by relative amount. You want an absolute position, use [`moveToPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToPosition%28int%29) instead.

Answer (score 0):

First initialize database obj like below
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDb.getReadableDatabase();

Put your parameter names into query.But I inserted it.

```
try{
      Cursor cursor=db.query(DB_helper.YourTableName, new String[]          {"_ID","Photopath","Name","Pos","Score","Fixed"}, null,null, null, null, null);     
        if(cursor.getCount()>0){
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         do{
        //cursor.getString(0); Means get String from first column(_ID)          
        USER_ID =cursor.getString(0);
        USERNAME=cursor.getString(3);
        USERTYPE=cursor.getString(5);
        PLANTID =cursor.getString(4);
         }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();                  
           db.close();                 
        }     

    }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();            
    }
```

You can store it values into String on into array list and use it anywhere.

Thanks